# Is it allowed to create an iphone application that is not for public use?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I mean, the app has a login screen, but **ONLY** customers from a company will receive the username and password, so **who is not customer of this company cannot use the application**.

Is that allowed?

Comment: I believe it is allowed, there are many apps that require you to have an account. But anyway, your question is offtopic.

Comment: @Tadeck : Not really. IMHO, I really think that developping an application is not only coding : it's also testing, technical reviews, ... and deploying/distributing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Apple may ask you to provide a "demo" account to test it.
On the other hand, I would use the "ad hoc" mode to distribute your app "over the air".
You can read more about [this method](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html).

Comment: can I using The traditional "iOS developer program" distribute apps using the ad hoc method?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can get more information [at this location](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) (Look for "Ad Hoc Distribution" )

Comment: Ad Hoc apps expire at least once per year, sometimes more often, and are limited to less than 100 devices max total.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can put it in to store but you have to specify in the description that the app is only  for people that have an account at your company.
2. Second variant is to get an enterprise developer account

Answer (score 1):

Yes , this is allowed and they are known as enterprise apps. You can put these app on a  private server that particular company and you can implement a login mechanism for a particular employee so that he can download that app...

for more info refer this https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: The iOS Enterprise program does NOT allow distributing apps to customers, only to employees.  And it's only for D&B rated corporations.